# MySQL Conditional Possible?

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, unix-timestamp

Im trying to change a Unix date from "01/01/1970" to "0"

Basically I have this:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(last_visit, '%d-%m-%Y') AS Last_Visit
```

So when I export this MySQL it's saying "Last Visit - 01/01/1970" which obviously is not correct.

So I thought I may need a conditional to state IF it says 1970 change it to "Never"

But Im a bit lost...

Comment: Why don't you just change the column's default value to `NULL`?

Comment: I could... I've only recently got into MySQL because I needed to edit a database & pull data from a prebuilt CMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to use `NULL` than `0` in this context.

You can use MySQL's [`NULLIF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) function to replace `last_visit` with `NULL` if it's equal to `0` (which is `01/01/1970`):

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(NULLIF(last_visit,0), '%d-%m-%Y') AS Last_Visit
```

Better yet, update the underlying table (then your original SQL would work fine as-is):

```
UPDATE mytable SET last_visit = NULL WHERE last_visit = 0
```

Comment: Perfect! I've added it in but it keeps the field blank when I export it as a CSV. Is there no way of making it put a message in there rather than null... Something like "Never"? Null is fine for now though.

Comment: @JasonMayo: How are you exporting as CSV?  If using [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html), you could simply specify that in your select list; e.g. `SELECT a, b, c, IFNULL(last_visit, 'Never') INTO OUTFILE ...`.